# How to cast int to PHP SPlEnum?

Tags: php, pecl, spl

I have an enumeration like this.

```
class TPNF_SplEnum  extends SplEnum {
    public static function InitList() {
        $instance = new static;

        static::$List = array_flip($instance->getConstList());
    }

    public static function GetName($key)     {
        return static::$List[$key];
    }

    public static function GetList() {
        return static::$List;
    }
}


class TPNF_Model_Url_ERelative extends TPNF_SplEnum {
    protected static $List;

    const __default = self::None;

    const None = 0;
    const Admin = 1;
    const Content = 2;
    const Includes = 3;
    const Plugins = 4;
    const Site = 5;
    const Theme = 6;
    const Themes = 7;
}
```

And I'd like to cast a int value into this enum but it doesn't work.

```
$url->Relative = new TPNF_Model_Url_ERelative((int)'2');
```

which is outputted (using print_r):

```
TPNF_Model_Url_ERelative Object ( [__default] => 2 )
```

instead of

```
TPNF_Model_Url_ERelativeContent
```

Comment: print_r() won't ever return what you want... print_r() has a fixed format for the output that it displays, depending on the datatype that you are displaying.

Comment: What you might want to do instead is add a magic __toString() method to your class that will return the appropriate value

Answer (score 0):

I have misconceived what SplEnum were.

You can assign their values to variables, but not themselves as if those were objects.

To convert from their value to the constant name and vice versa, there's no other way than creating functions for that. Functions which might be using `->getConstList`